# ¿Cómo añadir borde al menú de la toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, style

[image: Quiere mostrar solo el borde de afuera]

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners</item>
    </style>    

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp">
    </corners>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Quiero que solo sea visible el borde de afuera del menú. No sé como evitar los bordes que hay dentro del menú.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Espera un momento, tú le asignas un `style` a los items del `menú`  por lo que lo único que tienes que hacer es quitar el `<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@android:color/black"/>` o al color ponerle `@`null`. Pero, recuerda, solo debes hacerlo en donde sea que asignes los bordes

Comment: Tenía que asignar el **style** a **android:dropDownListViewStyle**